# Unnecessary title in Attachment viewer using primefaces p:media

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jboss, seam

When I view my attachment which is a .pdf file earlier uploaded, i get an unwanted "dynamiccontent.properties.seam" messag in the title bar of the viewer . 
The code used for this is as follows .

```
<h:panelGrid id="atachViewerPanel" style="width:99%; height:99%">
                        <p:media id="schemeMediaOutput" 
                            style="min-width:820px; min-height:580px"
                            value="#{fileUploadBean.imageStreamed}" width="100%"
                            height="100%" player="pdf" rendered="#{fileUploadBean.pdf}">
                        </p:media>
                    </h:panelGrid>
```

and the java function is as follows :

```
public StreamedContent getImageStreamed() {
        if (fileUploadData != null) {
            if (fileUploadData.getData() != null
                    && fileUploadData.getMime() != null) {
                imageStreamed = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(this.fileUploadData.getData()),
                        this.fileUploadData.getMime());
            }
        }
        return imageStreamed;
}
```

Please find the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yati.png) attached for better description

Comment: Find out where the title comes from. PF does not make this up. I suspect this is the title of the PDF document

Comment: That is not the title of the document. It appears for all the documents I upload and more interestingly it happens to the old version of my software where the source code is not even modified from past 1 year . Just wanted a confirmation whether its a chrome bug for pdf viewer.

Comment: Well, since you are using seam I doubt that Chrome (does it not happen in FF?) makes such a title up (something containing 'seam'), nor the pdf viewer (pdf.js)...

Comment: Yeah as i verified this problem isn't occurring in Firefox  . Please let me know if any solution found for this problem in chrome as we cant switch to FF .

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?